# File sent over TCP is created with type: application/octet-stream

Tags: c, file, tcp

I'm trying to transfer a file from a server to a client using TCP protocol.
I manage to send the whole syze of the file, but when the client creates the file, it cant be open. In this case, im sending an jpg file.

heres the code for server.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define PORT 59000

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
int port, fd, newfd, n, nw, addrlen;
int port_was_given = 0;
char buffer[128], *ptr, *topic, *data;
size_t result;
struct hostent *h;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
FILE *send;

if((fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))==-1)exit(1); //error
memset((void*)&addr,(int)'\0',sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

if (argc == 3) {
    port = atoi(argv[2]);
    port_was_given = 1;
}
    
if(port_was_given == 1) 
    addr.sin_port=htons((u_short)port);
else 
    addr.sin_port=htons((u_short)PORT);

if(bind(fd,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr))==-1)exit(1); //error

if(listen(fd,5)==-1)exit(1); //error

    while(1) {
        addrlen=sizeof(addr);
        if((newfd=accept(fd,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,&addrlen))==-1)exit(1); //erro
        h=gethostbyaddr((char*)&addr.sin_addr,sizeof(struct in_addr),AF_INET);
    
        while((n=read(newfd,buffer,128))!=0) {
            if(n==-1)exit(1);

        topic = strtok(buffer," ");
        topic = strtok(NULL," ");

        if (strcmp(topic, "Nacional\n")==0) {
            send = fopen("flag","r");
            fseek(send, 0L, SEEK_END); //vai ate ao fim do ficheiro
            int sz = ftell(send); //size of file
            fseek(send,0L,SEEK_SET);
            //rewind(send);
            data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*sz);
            result = fread(data,1,sz,send);
            //fseek(send,0L,SEEK_SET);
            fclose(send);
            char ptr2[300] = "REP ok ";
            char *ptrInt; //for s -> int
            sprintf(ptrInt, "%d", sz);
            strcat(ptr2, ptrInt);
            strcat(ptr2, " ");
            strcat(ptr2, data);
            strcat(ptr2, "\n");
            while(n>0) {
                nw=write(newfd,ptr2,n); //write n bytes on each cycle
            }

        }
            
        }
            
        
            
        close(newfd);
    }
    close(fd);
    exit(0);
}
```

Ok so the logic is: client requests a type of content, in this case the content is "Nacional", so the server has to send the "flag.jpg" to the client.
The answer of the server has the following type:

REP status size data

In which status can be "ok" or "nok". If "nok" then the file is not sent.
size is the size of the data.
data is data of the file itself.

Now the client.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 58000
#define NG 10
  
int main (int argc,char *argv[]) 
{

    /** ... variables declarations and other stuff ... */

    fdtcp=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if (fdtcp==-1) exit(1); // Erro

    inet_aton(ip, &address);  
    
    if (strcmp(lsname, "localhost")==0)
        newHost = gethostbyname("localhost");
    else
        newHost = gethostbyaddr((const void *)&address,sizeof ip,AF_INET);

    newPort = atoi(newport);  
        
    memset((void*)&addrtcp,(int)'\0',sizeof(addrtcp));  
    addrtcp.sin_family=AF_INET;     
    addrtcp.sin_addr.s_addr=((struct in_addr *)(newHost->h_addr_list[0]))->s_addr;  
    addrtcp.sin_port=htons((u_short)newPort);
        
    k = connect(fdtcp,(struct sockaddr*)&addrtcp,sizeof(addrtcp));
    if (k==-1) exit(1); // Erro
    
    // REQ Tn (Conteudo Solicitado)
    ptr = strcat(reqdata, tn);
    ptr = strcat(reqdata, "\n");

    // Envia-se o Comando REQ
    nreqleft = 25;
    while(nreqleft>0) {
        kwrite=write(fdtcp,ptr,nreqleft); 
        if (kwrite<=0) exit(1); // Erro
        nreqleft -= kwrite;
        ptr += kwrite;
    }

    // Recebe-se o Comando REP
    nreqleft = 128;
    ptr = &buffertcp[0];
    kread=read(fdtcp,ptr,nreqleft);
    if (kread==-1) exit(1); // Erro
    cmd = strtok(buffertcp, " ");   // REP
    cmd = strtok(NULL, " ");    // Status
    if(strcmp(cmd,"ok")) {
        printf("ERR\n");
        exit(1); // Erro
    }
    cmd = strtok(NULL, " ");    // Size
    size = atoi(cmd);
    // Recebem-se os Dados do ConteÃºdo Desejado
    nreqleft = size;
    char data[size];
    ptr = &data[0];
    while(nreqleft>0) {
        kread=read(fdtcp,ptr,nreqleft);
        if (kread==-1) exit(1); // Erro
        nreqleft -= kread;
        ptr += kread;
    }

    file = fopen("file","w");
    fwrite(data, 1, size, file);
    fclose(file);
    
    close(fdtcp); 

    // ---------------------------------------------------  //

    exit(0);
}
```

The "other stuff" part is just variables declarations and a UDP connection with another server which has nothing to do with this part, so I'm 100% sure it won't affect this part. In fact, on client.c, if I place an printf of the message received from the server, it will show "REP ok 31800 ?????" which ??? I assume would be the data of the file.

The problem is that the "file" created can't be open. Help?

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that 31800 is much larger than 300, and so when you append the `data` to your `ptr2` array in the server, you have buffer overrun. You can correct that by not sending the data with a separate `write()` call after sending your "header" in `ptr2`. Your `write()` loop looks like it will loop forever, but I am guessing you are not showing all of your code.

In the receiver, I don't see any attempt to parse the header to separate the header from the data. Since you read in up to 128 bytes, that read may have received both the header and some data of the file, and you make no attempt to detect and save that part of the file.

When debugging file transfer applications, I would start with textual files so that you can visually see the resulting file, and run a simple `diff` on the file you saved with the actual file to see if there are differences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well i might be wrong but are u suggesting that i call write() two times? Oh and the write() loop doesnt loop forever since i tested it.